# Fractional Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

I want to get a little help from fbm.

---

fBm $B_H(t)$ have below characteristics.

(1) stationary increments (Gaussian).

(2) Hurst parmeter $H > \frac{1}{2} $, it is positively correlated.

---

Therefore, $X(t)=B_H(t)-B_H(t-1)$ ($\text{t is integer}$) is discrete time Guassian process with identically distributed but not independent.

Here is the point.

When getting the sample $x_1, x_2, ... , x_n$ ... from $X(1), X(2), ... X(n)...$ I make the histogram of these sample.

**It looks Gaussian. How can it happen?**

---

First, I think it would be not Gaussian due to its dependence (correlation). But in reality, it is Gaussian.

I think it is not due to CLT. it is not about the sum of RVs. Furthermore, if $X(t)$ is not Guassian, its histogram is also not.

Could you give me your little intuition?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually is a form of CLT. Even though the $X_n$ are not independent, they are weakly dependent - $X_1$ and $X_n$ are very nearly independent, for large $n$. See [weakly dependent CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#CLT_under_weak_dependence) for example. At a glance, I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4419) which may interest you.

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness! But could you explain it in detail? I saw the weakly dependent CLT but it said the distribution $S_n$, not $X_n$. I need the connection between the distribution of $X_n$ and $S_n$, for large n. I will read the paper ASAP. Thank you so much again

Comment: @nimdrak CLT is a statement about the average of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, equivalent to a statement about the sum $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, which is probably what you saw. However, variations of the CLT also give convergence of the distribution (which sounds closer to what you are looking for), not just the mean. Trust me, it does answer your question, but I think you need more background regarding the basic CLT before asking these questions about weakly dependent CLT or trying to read the paper I linked. I would suggest reading chapter 3 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html for the basics

Comment: I agonized for a long time about finding the answer. But thanks to you, I finally find the answer and what to do after knowing that. I will study the chapter and the paper. You’re awesome!

Comment: @nimdrak Thanks, since you are new on the website let me point out that if a question has been answered, you should mark the answer as "accepted" (green checkmark) so others don't get confused.

Comment: I see. I mark it. Thank you so much!